# Elasticsearch cluster NodeStatsCollector time out when collecting data

Tags: elasticsearch

A few minutes after the elasticsearch cluster run, all nodes gives the error:

```
[ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.n.NodeStatsCollector] [node-1] collector [node_stats] timed out when collecting data
[ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.n.NodeStatsCollector] [node-1] collector [node_stats] timed out when collecting data
```

all nodes gives this error and indexer that is a java program index data whit bulk api very well. and there is no error in logs of my indexer program. but elastic search node gives this error.
i used 4 elasticsearch nodes and kibana in one machine whit windows server 2019 data center
the version of elasticsearch and kibana is 7.10.0 and Cluster Status is :

```
    {
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "successful" : 4,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "es-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "RRhGhaElfh5lUxGfsKg",
  "timestamp" : 1245375859907,
  "status" : "green",
  "indices" : {
    "count" : 1,
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 9,
      "primaries" : 3,
      "replication" : 2.0,
      "index" : {
        "shards" : {
          "min" : 9,
          "max" : 9,
          "avg" : 9.0
        },
        "primaries" : {
          "min" : 3,
          "max" : 3,
          "avg" : 3.0
        },
        "replication" : {
          "min" : 2.0,
          "max" : 2.0,
          "avg" : 2.0
        }
      }
    },
    "docs" : {
      "count" : 0,
      "deleted" : 0
    },
    "store" : {
      "size" : "36.1mb",
      "size_in_bytes" : 37936718,
      "reserved" : "0b",
      "reserved_in_bytes" : 0
    },
    "fielddata" : {
      "memory_size" : "0b",
      "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
      "evictions" : 0
    },
    "query_cache" : {
      "memory_size" : "0b",
      "memory_size_in_bytes" : 0,
      "total_count" : 0,
      "hit_count" : 0,
      "miss_count" : 0,
      "cache_size" : 0,
      "cache_count" : 0,
      "evictions" : 0
    },
    "completion" : {
      "size" : "0b",
      "size_in_bytes" : 0
    },
    "segments" : {
      "count" : 0,
      "memory" : "0b",
      "memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "terms_memory" : "0b",
      "terms_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "stored_fields_memory" : "0b",
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "term_vectors_memory" : "0b",
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "norms_memory" : "0b",
      "norms_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "points_memory" : "0b",
      "points_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "doc_values_memory" : "0b",
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "index_writer_memory" : "233.1mb",
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes" : 244509188,
      "version_map_memory" : "0b",
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "fixed_bit_set" : "0b",
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes" : 0,
      "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp" : -1,
      "file_sizes" : { }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "field_types" : [
        {
          "name" : "boolean",
          "count" : 3,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "date",
          "count" : 4,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "geo_point",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "integer",
          "count" : 8,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "ip",
          "count" : 2,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "keyword",
          "count" : 12,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "object",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "text",
          "count" : 17,
          "index_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "analysis" : {
      "char_filter_types" : [ ],
      "tokenizer_types" : [ ],
      "filter_types" : [
        {
          "name" : "stop",
          "count" : 3,
          "index_count" : 1
        }
      ],
      "analyzer_types" : [
        {
          "name" : "custom",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        }
      ],
      "built_in_char_filters" : [ ],
      "built_in_tokenizers" : [
        {
          "name" : "standard",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        }
      ],
      "built_in_filters" : [
        {
          "name" : "arabic_normalization",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "decimal_digit",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "lowercase",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "persian_normalization",
          "count" : 1,
          "index_count" : 1
        }
      ],
      "built_in_analyzers" : [ ]
    }
  },
  "nodes" : {
    "count" : {
      "total" : 4,
      "coordinating_only" : 0,
      "data" : 3,
      "data_cold" : 3,
      "data_content" : 3,
      "data_hot" : 3,
      "data_warm" : 3,
      "ingest" : 3,
      "master" : 3,
      "ml" : 0,
      "remote_cluster_client" : 4,
      "transform" : 3,
      "voting_only" : 1
    },
    "versions" : [
      "7.10.0"
    ],
    "os" : {
      "available_processors" : 48,
      "allocated_processors" : 24,
      "names" : [
        {
          "name" : "Windows Server 2019",
          "count" : 4
        }
      ],
      "pretty_names" : [
        {
          "pretty_name" : "Windows Server 2019",
          "count" : 4
        }
      ],
      "mem" : {
        "total" : "383.4gb",
        "total_in_bytes" : 411772076032,
        "free" : "127.2gb",
        "free_in_bytes" : 136611741696,
        "used" : "256.2gb",
        "used_in_bytes" : 275160334336,
        "free_percent" : 33,
        "used_percent" : 67
      }
    },
    "process" : {
      "cpu" : {
        "percent" : 0
      },
      "open_file_descriptors" : {
        "min" : -1,
        "max" : -1,
        "avg" : 0
      }
    },
    "jvm" : {
      "max_uptime" : "38.2m",
      "max_uptime_in_millis" : 2297261,
      "versions" : [
        {
          "version" : "14.0.2",
          "vm_name" : "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM",
          "vm_version" : "14.0.2+12-46",
          "vm_vendor" : "Oracle Corporation",
          "bundled_jdk" : true,
          "using_bundled_jdk" : false,
          "count" : 4
        }
      ],
      "mem" : {
        "heap_used" : "2.2gb",
        "heap_used_in_bytes" : 2433056080,
        "heap_max" : "50gb",
        "heap_max_in_bytes" : 53687091200
      },
      "threads" : 153
    },
    "fs" : {
      "total" : "6.5tb",
      "total_in_bytes" : 7196607758336,
      "free" : "6.2tb",
      "free_in_bytes" : 6888031485952,
      "available" : "6.2tb",
      "available_in_bytes" : 6888031469568
    },
    "plugins" : [ ],
    "network_types" : {
      "transport_types" : {
        "security4" : 4
      },
      "http_types" : {
        "security4" : 4
      }
    },
    "discovery_types" : {
      "zen" : 4
    },
    "packaging_types" : [
      {
        "flavor" : "default",
        "type" : "zip",
        "count" : 4
      }
    ],
    "ingest" : {
      "number_of_pipelines" : 2,
      "processor_stats" : {
        "gsub" : {
          "count" : 0,
          "failed" : 0,
          "current" : 0,
          "time" : "0s",
          "time_in_millis" : 0
        },
        "script" : {
          "count" : 0,
          "failed" : 0,
          "current" : 0,
          "time" : "0s",
          "time_in_millis" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any Idea for solve this error?